# How to share test interfaces between Go packages?

Tags: testing, go, quickcheck, property-testing

Go doesn't share code between test files of different packages, so definitions of test interfaces aren't automatically reused. How can we work around this in practice?

#### Example using `testing/quick`:

`foo/foo.go`:

```
package foo

type Thing int

const (
  X Thing = iota
  Y
  Z
)
```

`bar/bar.go`:

```
package bar

import (
  "foo"
)

type Box struct {
  Thing foo.Thing
}
```

We want to property test `foo`, so we define `testing/quick.Generate` on `Thing`:

`foo_test.go`:

```
package foo

import (
  "math/rand"
  "reflect"
  "testing"
  "testing/quick"
  "time"
)

func (_ Thing) Generate(r *rand.Rand, sz int) reflect.Value {
  return reflect.ValueOf(Thing(r.Intn(3)))
}

func TestGenThing(t *testing.T) {
  r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano()))
  for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    val, _ := quick.Value(reflect.TypeOf(Thing(0)), r)
    tng, _ := val.Interface().(Thing)
    t.Logf("%#v\n", tng)
  }
}
```

`quick.Value` returns `Thing`s in the range [0,3) as expected:

```
$ go test -v foo
=== RUN   TestGenThing
--- PASS: TestGenThing (0.00s)
        foo_test.go:20: 0
        foo_test.go:20: 1
        foo_test.go:20: 2
        foo_test.go:20: 1
        foo_test.go:20: 2
PASS
ok      foo     0.026s
```

Let's property test `bar` as well:

```
package bar

import (
  "math/rand"
  "reflect"
  "testing"
  "testing/quick"
  "time"

  "foo"
)

func (_ Box) Generate(r *rand.Rand, sz int) reflect.Value {
  val, _ := quick.Value(reflect.TypeOf(foo.Thing(0)), r)
  tng, _ := val.Interface().(foo.Thing)
  return reflect.ValueOf(Box{tng})
}

func TestGenBox(t *testing.T) {
  r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano()))
  for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    val, _ := quick.Value(reflect.TypeOf(Box{}), r)
    box, _ := val.Interface().(Box)
    t.Logf("%#v\n", box)
  }
}
```

But `Box.Generate` is broken. `foo_test.go` isn't available to `bar_test.go`, so `quick.Value()` doesn't use `Thing.Generate()`:

```
$ GOPATH=$PWD go test -v bar
=== RUN   TestGenBox
--- PASS: TestGenBox (0.00s)
        bar_test.go:24: bar.Box{Thing:3919143124849004253}
        bar_test.go:24: bar.Box{Thing:-3486832378211479055}
        bar_test.go:24: bar.Box{Thing:-3056230723958856466}
        bar_test.go:24: bar.Box{Thing:-847200811847403542}
        bar_test.go:24: bar.Box{Thing:-2593052978030148925}
PASS
ok      bar     0.095s
```

Is there a workaround for this? How do folks use `testing/quick` (or any other testing library with interfaces) in practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any code shared between packages must be in a non-test file. That doesn't mean it has to be included in any final builds though; you can use [build constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints) to exclude the files from normal builds, and [build tags](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies) to include them when running tests. For example, you can put your shared test code in a file prefixed with:

```
//+build testtools

package mypackage
```

(but *not* named _test.go). When you build, this will not be included in the build. When you test, you'd use something like:

```
go test -tags "testtools" ./...
```

This would include the constrained file in the build, and thereby make the shared code available to the tests.